# how to make half circle menu that show in the middle of the screen?

Tags: ios, objective-c, uiscrollview, menubar

i want to make a stylish scrollable menu that show in the middle of the screen over a table view

it is a half circle that the user can scroll for the items inside it the select item is the one in the middle the problem is the only i can found is full circle and im new in iOS

so i want to know how to make half circle scrollable menu bar ?

thanks in advance

Comment: This can  be helpful  https://www.cocoacontrols.com/controls/ghcontextmenu

Comment: @hardikhadwani yes something like that but always show not when i press and i can scroll between them

Comment: You can modify that code  as per your requirements.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

this link was helpful

https://www.cocoacontrols.com/controls/ghcontextmenu

not 100% what i want but it helped me